# How to measure head casing?

Tags: repair, measuring

I have, what seems like a trivial question. How on earth do you measure the size of a head casing? I measured as it shows in this picture, going from the bottom side of the 45's.

[image]

I measured my door (several times now because I thought I was insane) and it's 36". I went to Lowe's to try and buy just a piece of casing so they could cut it for me, but they said they can't do miter cuts. So I was left to buy a head casing set which costs me $20. The outside of the package says it has two 80" casing legs and a 36" header.

However, when I put it up on my door, it is clearly not 36" long. I pulled out a tape measure and the head casing I bought in the set measures 37.5" long. Nothing on the casing set I bought even measures up to 36"?! This is the second set I bought because the first set I got, I assumed in mistakenly bought the set that had the 38" header (there was paint all over the packaging).

What on earth is going on? Have I been measuring these things all wrong?

Comment: The pre-packaged casing kit may very well have the pieces cut a extra long for a 36" door so that they can be trimmed to fit precisely. That kind of kit is really not a cost effective option over waking over to the molding and casing aisle and selecting casing (and using a low cost miter box kit).

Comment: 3-0 o is the opening 3'0" the trim is wider by the thickness at a minimum when cut on a 45

Comment: @MichaelKaras that's what I was guessing too after I got two in a row that were oversized. I didn't like the option about getting the whole kit, but I didn't even think of the miter box kit! It would have been cheaper for me to buy one piece of casing and the kit.